# Why am I getting 'A non-serializable value is detected in the state' warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I was making a movie review app where I used Redux for storing and fetching the data, even though I left my state empty this error was still showing. Below is the code of the redux movie store.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
    
}

const MovieSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'movie',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchmovie: async (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);
    },
    addmovie: (state) => {

    }
  }
})

export const { fetchmovie }  = MovieSlice.actions;
export default MovieSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Are You sure that the problem is not caused by another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux reducer functions are pure, ***synchronous*** functions. The `fetchmovie` reducer is declared `async` which means it implicitly returns a Promise. Redux-Toolkit slice reducers can either mutate the state ***or*** return a new state value. The code is returning a Promise and it's stored in the Redux store as the `movie` state value.

Remove the `async` declaration so `fetchmovie` is synchronous.

```js
const MovieSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'movie',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    fetchmovie: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);
    },
    addmovie: (state) => { },
  },
});
```

If `fetchmovie` *really* is supposed to be asynchronous then it needs to be declared as a thunk and the reducer cases handled in the slice's `extraReducers` property.

Example:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
    
}

export const fetchmovie = createAsyncThunk(
  "movie/fetchmovie",
  async (_, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      // ... asynchronous fetching logic
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);

const MovieSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'movie',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addmovie: (state) => { },
  },
  extraReducers: builder => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchmovie.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(fetchmovie.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        console.log(action.payload);
        state.loading = false;
        ...
      })
      .addCase(fetchmovie.rejected, (state, action) => {
        console.log(action.payload);
        state.loading = false;
        ...
      });
  },
})

export const { addmovie }  = MovieSlice.actions;
export default MovieSlice.reducer;
```